# Microwave problems

Tags: electrical, microwave-oven

I have a small sunbeam microwave that I don't use that often. I keep it unplugged when it isn't in use. Lately, when I plug it in, the keypad doesn't activate and the display doesn't light up. However, the turntable turns by itself without being turned on, and the light inside the microwave is on.

Comment: Sounds like something has gone wrong with the control board. It's probably not worth the time and expense to attempt repair.

Comment: Can you post the model number?

Comment: I would do a teardown and look for anything physical/mechanical that's out of whack, like a loose connector or corroded terminals.  If it's easy to fix, go for it, otherwise I agree, the unit is probably a write-off.